# WiFi Turns off when Ethernet plugged in

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, bios, ethernet

HP Elitebook 840 G2. When Ethernet is plugged in, The wifi disconnects. The adaptor remains enabled, but Windows says 'WiFi Turned off'. Clicking the WiFi option seems to turn it back on again for five seconds (it returns a list of found networks) but then it goes off again.

- Fully up to date windows, 1803
- Driver fully up to date from Intel
- BIOS updated
- BIOS reset to defaults
- Power saving for adaptor turned off
- LAN/WLAN switching turned off in BIOS

I'm a bit mystified by this. It did seem ok until it updated to 1803 but I'm not strictly sure if it started right after that.

I would have blamed the switching in the BIOS but it is turned off.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: So many issues with 1803, hopefully they will get fixed on the next build.

Comment: @Moab - I have never been able to use an Ethernet and Wireless adapter at the same time on Windows.  There is a way to force it, but I am not in front of a device, I can investigate what it's called

Comment: @Ramhound never tried it but the question is worded like it worked for them until recently.

Comment: by chance is your computer domain joined?

Another thought, go to network adapters, select your wifi, click configure, go to advanced tab. Somwhere on the list should be an option "disable upon wire connect". Make sure that is not enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem on HP Elitebook 840 G2 with Windows 10 (1703). Please try updating or completely removing the driver/software "HP Hotkey Support". I uninstalled the whole thing and it seemed to help on my laptop.

I have to say it's really annoying from HP that the software name doesn't anyhow indicate that it has anything to do with the networking! It's just mentioned in the release notes/fixes field of the software version updates: "Fixes an issue on a system that has entered suspend/hibernate mode where HP LAN-Wireless protection does not function properly after the system resume from suspend/hibernation. " (https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/swdetails/hp-elitebook-840-g2-notebook-pc/7343202/swItemId/ob-207415-1 )